# compiler segfault when printf is added (gcc 10.2 aarch64_none-elf- from arm)

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, arm, u-boot, device-tree

I know this is not adequate for stack overflow question, but ..
This is a function in scripts/dtc/libfdt/fdt_ro.c of u-boot v2021.10.

```
const void *fdt_getprop_namelen(const void *fdt, int nodeoffset,
                const char *name, int namelen, int *lenp)
{
    int poffset;
    const struct fdt_property *prop;

    printf("uuu0 nodeoffset = 0x%x, name = %s, namelen = %d\n", nodeoffset, name, namelen);
    prop = fdt_get_property_namelen_(fdt, nodeoffset, name, namelen, lenp,
                     &poffset);
    //printf("uuu1 prop = 0x%lx, *lenp = 0x%x, poffset = 0x%x\n", prop, *lenp, poffset);
    if (!prop)
        return NULL;

    /* Handle realignment */
    if (fdt_chk_version() && fdt_version(fdt) < 0x10 &&
        (poffset + sizeof(*prop)) % 8 && fdt32_to_cpu(prop->len) >= 8)
        return prop->data + 4;
    return prop->data;
}
```

When I build the program, if I uncomment the second printf, the compiler seg-faults.
I have no idea. Is it purely compiler problem(I think so it should never die at least)? or can it be linked to my fault somewhere in another code? Is there any method to know the cause of the segfault? (probably not.).

Comment: You are dereferncing `lenp` in that printf. Are you sure that it points to a valid location instead of, for example, `NULL`?

Comment: Chan Kim, Try `printf("prop:%p lenp:%p poffset:%d\n", prop, lenp, poffset);` and report results.

Comment: Possibly the damage is done in `fdt_get_property_namelen_()`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica changing to %p is the same.

Comment: If the compiler itself segfaults (as you appear to be saying) then that's a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @G.M. Right I think so. It's not a run-time segfault. compiler should never die, but should tell me what I'm doing wrong before my running the program.

Comment: @ChanKim could you show the __verbatim__ error log of the compilation?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Hi, this isn't an urgent problem for me so I'll report when I'm back at work and have some time for this. Thanks!

Comment: @ChanKim [changing to %p is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70459997/compiler-segfault-when-printf-is-added-gcc-10-2-aarch64-none-elf-from-arm?noredirect=1#comment124552306_70459997) is incomplete.  Pleae report the entire verbatim result of `printf("prop:%p lenp:%p poffset:%d\n", prop, lenp, poffset);`.  Notice code uses `lenp`, not `*lenp`.

Comment: Since it is u-boot, you may kick a binary size over a limit and this can make things segfault (I would think the linker script might check).  Ie, the board you have has limited internal RAM, where u-boot is placed.  You made the code hit the bss/stack space and it crashes.  Everyone needs more context on the call.  You could give a reference to the system (STMxx-dev-board, etc) and a Link to the git code you use.  The fdt might become corrupt, etc.

Comment: `the compiler seg-faults` But anyway, you _need_ to post more context. Where are the sources from? How were they modified? Can you post them on git* repo? What compiler options are you using? What is the output of `...-gcc -v`? I.e. Please create a full [MCVE]. What should I do, with all the steps, to get the compiler to segfault on my PC? Maybe you should post a bug report at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ , if you are _completely 100% sure_ it's the compiler and not something else.

Comment: If the compiler actually seg-faults, it can also be that you have a damaged development machine.  Ie, you have installed incompatible libraries and/or you have defective RAM or disk.  It is possible there is a compiler bug, but if u-boot recommended this compiler and you have not significantly altered u-boot, it is highly unlikely it is a stock gcc bug.  Although possible, like stray neutrinos, etc.  That is why I assume you meant a run-time crash when u-boot runs.  You can probably get the symbols and run the compiler under GDB.  GCC people will want the preprocessed source causing the issue.

Comment: You can eliminate development hardware by reproducing it on another machine, if it is a build time issue.  `xxx-xxx-gcc -E rest-of-command` will preprocess the source to make a self-contained example.  I expect it is actually the linking phase if it is an **actual** build time bug.  What ever linker you have, u-boot has a custom linker file and it is probably the least tested aspect of the tool chain, but I would expect the u-boot developers would have encountered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting a segmentation fault when running the compiler itself, the compiler has a bug. There are some errors in your code, but those should result in compile-time diagnostics (warnings or error messages), never a compile-time crash.

The code in your question is incomplete (missing declarations for `fdt_get_property_namelen_`, `printf`, `NULL`, etc.). Reproduce the problem with a complete self-contained source file and submit a bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("uuu1 prop = 0x%lx, *lenp = 0x%x, poffset = 0x%x\n", prop, *lenp, poffset);
```

1. `prop` is a pointer, so I'd use `%p` instead of `%lx`
2. `lenp` is a pointer, so I'd make sure that it points to valid memory

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that and removed the 3rd bullet.

Comment: Hi, if lenp is NULL or doesn't point valid memory, it should be killed during run time. This is a compile time seg-fault.

Comment: @ChanKim: Compile time seg-fault??? Hell, I ain't never heard of that. If your compiler crashes during compilation, then the bug in is the compiler, not in your code.

Comment: Neither of those problems should cause a seg fault in the compiler itself.